# reading a file with mutiple lines and trying to split into a string array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

Hi i have a txt file with loads of numbers each number is randomly scattered across the file and when i read  the file in as a string and try to subdivide it into individual numbers in an array i get the issue of
ie my file contains

```
         1234

         3467


         22222
```

i didvide the numbers into string array String sub[] however every number goes into sub[0] ie sub[0] = 1234
3467
22222

whereas my desired output for sub[0] would be 1234
my code is below
`

```
File file = new File(s);
        String gg;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                gg = in.nextLine();

                // String temp = gg.replaceAll("\\s*[\\r\\n]+\\s*", "").trim();
                String temp = gg.replace('\n', ' ');
                String[] sub = temp.split(" ");
                System.out.println(sub[0]);
```

`

and the output im getting for sub[0] is a whole bunch of numbers when i only want one  which in above example it should be 1234

the comment is one of the ways i tried
i also tried using .replaceall the char one '\n' but it didnt work and .replaceall "\s"

Comment: Could you please clarify the question - perhaps some sample input..?  Is your file format separated by a ' ' (space) character?

Comment: What does your file look like? And why do you expect the return value of `in.nextLine()` to contain linebreaks? The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) say "This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end"

Comment: @synapticloop hopefully thats better the edit

Comment: Are you testing in MAC computer with file in linux format (line ends with `\n`). I have no way to test, but the only explanation that I found for your results, is that `nextLine()` reads until next `\r`, but not found any, and read until the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code (from what I can see) should work fine - you are trying to split a line on the " " character - but it is only a single line...

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        String gg = "";
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            gg = in.nextLine().trim();  // <- trim of whitespace
            System.out.println(gg);

            // maybe the line is all blank ??? best to check

            // convert the number to an int here...

            // determine min/max/average - need some variables :)

        }
    }
```

Comment: cheers for the help but i think i explained the problem poorly but i edited the post there

Comment: I would have a look at your linefeed characters in the text file as `in.nextLine()` will give you a single line if the linefeed character is in `\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]` - which _should_ work - and then the `String temp = gg.replace('\n', ' ');` should do nothing.  Perhaps it is time to start putting in some print debugging, or stepping through the code...

Answer (score 0):

put string array outside scope of while loop i assumed length is 3 btw replace this with whatever it is

```
String line;
        String sub[] = new String[100];

        try {
            while((line = buffread.readLine()) != null) {
                int i=0;
                sub[i] = line;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(sub[0]);

        }
```

output is 1234

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something strange about the whitespace inside your file, the following should work. Just ignore the whitespace and concentrate on collecting what isn't. If this doesn't work, we'll need to look more closely at the content of your file. Please report!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Nums {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Path.of(args[0]))) {
            String[] nums = s.tokens().toArray(String[]::new);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```